# Kotlin Native compile jar and framework

Tags: android, ios, gradle, kotlin-native

I'm building a multiplatform library for Android and iOS. My gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.4.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
group 'com.example'
version '0.0.1'

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

kotlin {
    jvm()
    // This is for iPhone simulator
    // Switch here to iosArm64 (or iosArm32) to build library for iPhone device
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework()
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
                implementation("com.ionspin.kotlin:bignum:0.2.2")
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.ionspin.kotlin:bignum:0.2.2")
            }
        }
        jvmTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test')
                implementation kotlin('test-junit')
            }
        }
        iosMain {
        }
        iosTest {
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```

Im using a third party library and I'm using it like this:

```
fun test(value: String): Int {
    return BigDecimal.parseString(value).toBigInteger().intValue()
}
```

The problem is when I build the .jar the bignum library isn't included, and when I use the lib in an Android project I get an exception ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ionspin.kotlin.bignum.decimal.BigDecimal".

Is there a way to include third party libs in the .jar for Android and .framework for iOS?

Comment: can you share a github.com of your gradle files, then I can help you, the best official example is here https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-sample, and the documentation is here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/samples.html, you need to use child gradle modules

Comment: The issue is that the Android and iOS projects are really big and I don't want to include them in a new project as a child gradle modules.

Comment: Could it be how the library is published? Did you try asking to the library author too? I've tried with other 3rd party libs and the problem doesn't occur indeed. [This reference](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-native-dependency-is-not-accessible-at-runtime-on-the-target-platform/18547) could help too.

Comment: I am actually using this library https://github.com/korlibs/krypto the one in the question was just for example. And Krypto lib has the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JVM**

So, the only way I've found to generate a **Fat JAR** that works like you expect is by adding two *custom gradle tasks* in `project:build.gradle.kts` of your KMP library after applying the **java** plugin.

```kotlin
plugins {
    [...]
    id("java")
}

[...]

kotlin {
    jvm {
        [...]
        compilations {
            val main = getByName("main")
            tasks {
                register<Copy>("unzip") {
                    group = "library"
                    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "3rd-libs")
                    project.delete(files(targetDir))
                    main.compileDependencyFiles.forEach {
                        println(it)
                        if (it.path.contains("com.")) {
                            from(zipTree(it))
                            into(targetDir)
                        }
                    }
                }
                register<Jar>("fatJar") {
                    group = "library"
                    manifest {
                        attributes["Implementation-Title"] = "Fat Jar"
                        attributes["Implementation-Version"] = archiveVersion
                    }
                    archiveBaseName.set("${project.name}-fat")
                    val thirdLibsDir = File(buildDir, "3rd-libs")
                    from(main.output.classesDirs, thirdLibsDir)
                    with(jar.get() as CopySpec)
                }
            }
            tasks.getByName("fatJar").dependsOn("unzip")
        }

    }
    [...]
}
```

You then must launch the `fatJar` gradle task that generate a *.jar* file with the 3rd libraries classes extracted from their corresponding *jar* archives.

You can customize the two custom gradle scripts even more in order to better fit your needs (here I only included dependencies in **com.*** package).

[image]

Then in your Android app `app:build.gradle` file you can use it as you did or simply

`implementation files('libs/KMLibraryTest001-fat-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')`

**iOS**

As you ask also for the iOS part in your title (even if it's a second citizen in the main topic of your question) you need only to use `api` instead of `implementation` for your 3rd party library along with the export option of the framework.

```kotlin
ios() {
    binaries {
        framework() {
            transitiveExport = true // all libraries
            //export(project(":LibA")) // this library project in a transitive way
            //export("your 3rd party lib") // this 3rd party lib in a transitive way
        }
    }
}
```

And you can find a full reference [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries).

Comment: Hi I changed implementation("com.ionspin.kotlin:bignum:0.2.2") to api("com.ionspin.kotlin:bignum:0.2.2") on both occurrences in .gradle file and it still doesn't work. 

I'm using kotlin multiplatform 1.4.20 and gradle wrapper version 6.7.1. I tried to build the .jar with IntelliJ Run -> Build and I still get the same exception ClassNotFoundException, which means the third party dependency isn't included.

Comment: I still get the same error. I build the .jar with the "Build artifacts" method and attach the 3rd party lib metadata jar to the built jar. The final jar is now larger than before, but when I try to include it into another Android project (implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])) I still get the ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @box the above comments are outdated ;)

Comment: i accepted your answer. However haven't managed to make it work, I get the Copy method not found.

Comment: @box Which template do you use for your library? I suppose you use IntelliJ IDEA with kotlin multiplatform library template. This template works out of the box if you include the java plugin and copy and paste my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [Krypto library](https://github.com/korlibs/krypto/tree/master/krypto/src), it has

```
androidMain
jsMain
jvmMain
mingwX64Main
nativPosixMain
```

Which means 5 kind of binaries are generated to support 5 platforms
Convincingly, this explains that each platform expects its own binary

for example,

windows -- `DLL` file
linux -- `so` file
java -- `JAR` file
mac -- `dylib` file

A JAR gets loaded into JVM, but IOS does not use JVM
Separate your Utility functions which has a common logic and write gradle to target multiple platforms

If you want to start with **pure multiplatform**, you can try this [Official Example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/androidNativeActivity)

Or create a sub gradle module and create a library project which is common to IOS as well as Android

The possible targets are properly documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-supported-platforms.html)

I have created a application which publishes the binary to local repository and re-uses in the `MainActivity` -- you can get the code [here](https://github.com/dickensas/kotlin-gradle-templates/tree/master/android-multiplatform)

modify the `local.properties` for android SDK location and use

```
gradlew assemble
```

to build the APK and test it yourself

open the `mylib\build.gradle.kts` folder and you can see the targets `jvm` and `iosX64` , `jvm` is used for android

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct using `api` instead of `implementation` should fix your problem, though I didn't try it out yet on the Native part

See [Api and implementation separation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)